# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore only generating models with fields of type string

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0, swagger-codegen

So I have a group model like this:

```
public class GroupDTO {
    [Required]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But the generated model by swagger looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "string",
    "name": "string"
  }
]
```

It should look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "name": "string"
  }
]
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Swashbuckle treat Guids as string. That's the expected behavior

Comment: @Mike Acts the same without the nullable operator.

Comment: @ceferrari Ah thanks, when I used Swashbuckle on a .NET Framework project it generated the models like I described below the generated model.

Answer (score 0):

Guids are treated as strings by Swashbuckle.

Answered by @ceferrari in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.Examples to add examples to your swagger calls that have valid values.